# Setup Cross-Database query in Azure SQL Database through SSMS

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, ssms

I was following [this](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-database-support-blog/cross-database-query-in-azure-sql-database/ba-p/369126) article to setup cross database query in Azure SQL Database. The only difference is that, My origin DB and master DB is same, i.e., I want to setup cross query from master database.

Now according to `step 5`, we need to create database scoped credential in master DB. But when I run this query in SSMS, I get `Database credentials are not supported in master database.`, How to resolve this?

Comment: Why do you want a cross database query in `master` in an Azure SQL Database? That certainly seems wrong. What does the question have to do with MySQL (A completely different product) and SSMS (which is an IDE for SQL Server)?

Comment: My sql server has multiple databases in it, now when I run a query in azure sql, it picks up master as default database, whereas I want to access some table from remotedb! Removed the tag of mysql though

Comment: *"t picks up master as default database"* Then specify the database you need to connect to; That's shown in step 6. This most certainly smells like an [XY problem](//xyproblem.info). If you create a linked server to the `master` database in an Azure SQL Database, the only database you'll be able to access is `master`; which is pointless.

Comment: Yes, but I'll need AppCredential for that which we had setup in step 5

Comment: Yes, which you create in your database `RemoteDb`.

Comment: Not ideally at all. If you want 3 part naming you functionality you should not be using Azure SQL Databases; they are isolated DBs.

Comment: No!! I created that in OriginDB that is master DB in my case.

Comment: So you are creating user based objects in `master`? Well there's your issue.

Comment: Yes, something like that, I am not sure!!

Comment: Its all the same as explained, I just need this to be applicable on master instead of OriginDB

Comment: You can't, the error tells you that. Time to painstakingly move all your user objects into a user database, and then correct all your connection strings. Good luck!